# How to use protobuf-net 3 with ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, protobuf-net

I have seen [this repository](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreMvcProtobufFormatters/tree/master/src); it works with a previous version of protobuf, after enabling `AllowSynchronousIO`, but I don't know how to use it with version 3.

Could you give any hint on using protobuf-net 3 with ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that linked package, but if it worked with V2 it *should* also work with V3; are you seeing a specific issue? If so, what? But as per my answer below: protobuf-net ships it's own input/output formatter library for asp.net core

Comment: Also: thanks for reminding me that I need to do a massive overhaul of documentation and add examples for the new features. Sadly, there just aren't enough hours in the day, and reality sometimes dictates that other priorities (like family and paid work) had to come first.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use [protobuf-net.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net.AspNetCore/) and use `AddProtoBufNet`, a bit like [here](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.TestWeb/Startup.cs#L21). This configures input/output formatters for content negotiation, using the protobuf-net v3 API and "pipelines" (rather than `Stream`).

You can use the pipeline APIs directly, but it is a bit more complex than just reading/writing to/from a `Stream`. Happy to add an example if needed, though.